# Update PSData Properties in Powershell Module Manifest through a PS Script

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to put some new properties in my PSData Hashtable within the PrivateData Hashtable in my Powershell Module Manifest File.

However, since I plan on putting this into an Automated build system, I would like to make a PS function that can update the properties.

In my current psd1 file, I have ReleaseNotes, and would like to populate that with my build system through a powershell script. The powershell script would have a variable that is the Release Notes, and will be able to populate the ReleaseNotes property in my PSData hashtable.

How would I go about approaching this?

Comment: See [`Update-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/update-modulemanifest?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 0):

Beware that something like

```
Update-ModuleManifest -Path .\Osmium.psd1 -ReleaseNotes "abc.txt"
```

will "destroy" the current psd1 file by autogenerating the complete file again with all the entries and comments. A better approach would be to import the psd1 file with Import-LocalizedData, updating the releasenotes property and saving the hashtable back to the psd1 file.

Unfortunately there is no cmdlet for that so you would have to write a ToString() method for a hashtable that considers properties which are hashtables too.

Comment: I wrote a function that converts a hashtable into a string and published it in my blog: http://poshadmin.de/?p=1423