# Equivalent Groovy ConfigSlurper format for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gradle, groovy

We have a large number of groovy/gradle configuration files that are created by the ConfigSlurper class.

We are investigating to move our scripts over to PowerShell and quickly realized that the format is not JSON format.

I'm not finding a lot out there on the 'industry standard' configuration format.  Yes there is JSON and INI... but that doesn't nearly seem as powerful as the groovy Config capabilities.

What do people use out there?
Has anyone found an equivalent to the goovy/gradle config files?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax-wise, the closest equivalent is to use a `.psd1` file containing a PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal, which you can read into an in-memory hashtable using [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile).

However, note that - as of PowerShell 7.3.1 - there is no way to create such a file *programmatically* - [GitHub issue #11300](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11300) discusses future enhancements to allow this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61251209/45375) provides custom code for writing `.psd1` files and also discusses alternative data formats, including JSON, which is also worth considering.

**Example**:

The PowerShell equivalent of the following Groovy config file (taken [from the docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html)):

```
grails.webflow.stateless = true
smtp {
     mail.host = 'smtp.myisp.com'
     mail.auth.user = 'server'
}
resources.URL = 'http://localhost:80/resources'
```

is:

```
@{
  grails    = @{ webflow = @{ stateless = $true } }
  smtp      = @{
    mail    = @{ 
      host = 'smtp.myisp.com' 
      auth = @{ user = 'server' }
    }
  }
  resources = @{ URL = 'http://localhost:80/resources' }
}
```

As you can see, there are similarities in syntax, but PowerShell's is invariably more verbose, primarily because it doesn't support implicit nesting of the hasthables (maps, in Groovy terms).

Parsing the above with `Import-PowerShellDataFile` results in a single, nested hashtable whose top-level keys as `grails`, `smtp`, and `resources` - but not the the order of the entries is *not* guaranteed to match the order in the input file.

Comment: Wow... ya that's definitely not an option for a configuration file :)  Thank you for all the feedback.  I think JSON it is - we will "slurp" then save as json to migrate the conversion files i guess.  Not as powerful, but may just be the way.  If i don't hear of any other answers, i'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @Julian, that sounds like a plan, given that it's easy to both read and write JSON in PowerShell, but note that JSON will be even more verbose, given that it also doesn't support nested maps (objects) and requires property names to always be double-quoted.